# Thank you for helping

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have send one extra colum but my table has 7 elements why my sql want 1 extra?? as u can see i have send $na 2 times

```
$sqlQ="insert into users values ('".$na."','".$na."','".$num."','".$gender."','".$user."','".$email."','".$pass."')";
$result= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlQ);
```

Comment: Side note: your title is not really explicit.

Comment: You need to add the db table schema for users. You should also change to use prepared and parameterized queries so you're protected against sql injection

Comment: I always prefer to list the columns I'm inserting into rather than just list the VALUES.  This makes debugging easier and also stop bugs creeping in if columns are swapped during database changes.

Comment: You need to change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually this is not good practice to insert the value in the database.
i recommend always use something like this.

```
$sqlQ="insert into users (tableField,tableField1) values ('$value','$value1')";
```

> Note:never put auto increment field name OR value in the query.and always use `prepared statements` to avoid sql injection attack.given code is also vulnerable.if you do not know about prepared statement raise question or google it.